# Change archive page's breadcrumb path in WordPress (Yoast Seo)

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs, yoast

I'm using **Yoast Seo** plugin to show breadcrumbs under my header.

I've changed the default `author` url to `about/team` by putting the code below in **functions.php**.

```
add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');  
function change_author_permalinks()  
{  
    global $wp_rewrite;  
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = '/about/team';
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base. '/%author%';  
}
```

so `mysite.com/author/author name` will be `mysite.com/about/team/author name`.

I want the breadcrumb to be like this when someone visits `mysite.com/about/team/authorname`:

> author name « خانه » درباره‌ ما » اعضا

But it shows a path for an archive:

> author name خانه » بایگانی

Is there a way to override this manually?

**Translations:**

- خانه: Home
- درباره ما: About (About us)
- اعضا: Team
- بایگانی: Archive

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Questions are expected to show some effort at solving yourself - what have you tried? (Tip: Yoast's SEO plugin has some pretty excellent action hooks in it for the breadcrumbs - try searching Google a bit to see what you find).

Comment: Thank you. I've searched the options in Wp dashbord and Googled my question but no good answer was found.

Answer (score 0):

For more advanced breadcrumb items manipulation, besides [Yoast's basic options](https://yoast.com/help/implement-wordpress-seo-breadcrumbs/), you can use the '**wpseo_breadcrumb_links**' filter.
Here are a few examples that can help you get started: https://gist.github.com/amboutwe/ea0791e184668a5c7bd7bbe357c598e9